# Best possible bit array for Numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba, memory-efficient, bitarray

I need to create a bit array in Python. So far, I've discovered that one can generate very memory-efficient arrays using the [bitarray](https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/) module.

However, my final intention is to use `@vectorize` decorator from [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/index.html). Numba works with only a limited amount of [Python](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html) and [numpy](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html) features and bitarray is not one of them.

My question is, what's the best memory-efficient way of creating bit arrays *using the structures that are supported by Numba*?

I would go with numpy arrays, but I've done a quick memory test and it doesn't look good:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import random
>>> from bitarray import bitarray
>>> from sys import getsizeof
>>> N = 10000

>>> a = bitarray(N)
>>> print(type(a), getsizeof(a))
<class 'bitarray.bitarray'> 96

>>> b = np.random.randint(0, 1, N)
>>> print(type(b), b.nbytes)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 40000

>>> c = [random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(N)]
>>> print(type(c), getsizeof(c))
<class 'list'> 87624
```

(not to say anything about `list`)

---

EDIT: As a side question, does anyone have any idea why `getsizeof` returns such an unrealistically low number for `bitarray`? I have just noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply specify the data type:

```
N=1000
b = np.random.randint(0, 1, N)
print(type(b),getsizeof(b))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 4096
c = np.random.randint(0, 1, N, dtype=np.bool)
print(type(b),getsizeof(c))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 1096
```

And for your side-question, numpy constructs much more in the numpy object then bitarrray so it is less efficient in terms of total memory of the object.

**EDIT:**

The memory of the object in python consist of all methods implemented in the object, at least their references to the code, attributes and items such as `object.size` which is a tuple in numpy that consist of integers, etc. In your list, you have several references to methods such as `pop`, `delete`, etc., and it consist of integers arranged in different nodes (list is an extended implementation of a classical linked list combined with other methods, see [data structures](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html) in official docs).

Taking all of that into consideration, best practice is to use an appropriate data structure that works well in your pipeline, and specify types whenever is possible. Since you use `numba`, numpy seems the best fit. Memory is not always the issue.

Comment: I wonder if this is entirely correct. At least the [numba documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/reference/types.html) states that 'booleans are represented as bytes' (i.e. not bits).  I think that in your example the difference we see is between something like `np.int32` and a `np.int8`. See also the [numpy documentation on types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html).